# SQLite and large transactions

Tags: sqlite

I have a project in Unity 3D and I am using a precompiled SQLite library for Android, OSX, iOs and Windows.
On Android when using large transactions my database file can grow from 1MB to 1GB.

Doing this for example on OSX is not behaving the same, the database does not get that large. Before completing the transaction I get a "Disk I/O error".
I was trying to figure that out by comparing different PRAGMA statement but could not find anything.

I am probably missing something but I don't know what.

Edit: I have run the sqlite3_analyzer and I got 
`Size of the file in bytes......................... 3715072`
but the file size on the disk is around 1GB

This is how the SQL query where the error happens looks like

```
                                CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LogRange AS
            SELECT
                l.EntityKey AS EntityKey,
                l.TableName AS TableName,
                l.OrderNumber AS StartOrderNumber,
                l2.OrderNumber AS EndOrderNumber
            FROM IncomingLog AS l 
            INNER JOIN IncomingLog l2 ON l2.OrderNumber > l.OrderNumber AND l2.EntityKey = l.EntityKey AND l2.TableName = l.TableName AND l2.Type = 2
            WHERE l.Type = 0;

            DELETE FROM IncomingLog WHERE Id IN 
            (
                SELECT l.Id
                FROM IncomingLog l
                INNER JOIN LogRange lr ON lr.EntityKey = l.EntityKey AND lr.TableName = l.TableName AND l.OrderNumber >= lr.StartOrderNumber AND l.OrderNumber <= lr.EndOrderNumber
            );
            DROP TABLE LogRange;

            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CompressedLog AS
            SELECT
                l.*
            FROM IncomingLog l
            LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT
                    1 as Id,
                    EntityKey,
                    TableName,
                    MAX(OrderNumber) as OrderNumber
                FROM IncomingLog WHERE Type = 1 OR Type = 2
                GROUP BY EntityKey 
            ) updateOrDeleteLogs ON updateOrDeleteLogs.OrderNumber > l.OrderNumber AND updateOrDeleteLogs.EntityKey = l.EntityKey AND updateOrDeleteLogs.TableName = l.TableName
            WHERE ((l.Type=1 OR l.Type = 2) AND updateOrDeleteLogs.Id IS NULL) OR l.Type = 0;

            DELETE FROM IncomingLog;
            INSERT INTO IncomingLog SELECT * FROM CompressedLog;

            DROP TABLE CompressedLog;
```

And this is how the IncomingLog table look like

```
CREATE TABLE IncomingLog (OrderNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Id TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, Type INETEGER, CreationDate DATETIME, EntityType TEXT, EntityKey TEXT, TableName TEXT, Data TEXT)
```

The data column stores jsons so it can take a lot of space.
In my example there are 5000 rows in the IncomingLog table.

I have implemented the extended error code for my wrapper library and now I get SQLITE_IOERR_GETTEMPPATH (6410).
So now I have to find a solution for this.

Comment: What do these transactions do? Insertions? Deletions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and the solution.
Apparently SQLite on Android could not find a a temporary directory and this is the reason why I got the error.
The only workaround for this that I have found is set the PRAGMA temp_store_directory.
The only problem with this is that the PRAGMA temp_store_directory is deprecated but I could not find any other solution.

As for why the database is growing up to 1GB I still don't have an answer.